# How to handle and escape varbinary database entries correctly in python

Tags: python, sql-server, escaping, varbinary

I have a script where I first read a table, saving an `int` and a `varbinary(512)` in form of a `some_set = set()`, `some_set.add((db_row['int_val'], db_row['varbin_val'))`. A set of tuples..

There may be multiple rows having the same `int_val`/`varbin_val` combination, but those are the duplicates.

Now saving them seems to work fine. But when I try to `INSERT INTO` said saved rows, from the source table to the destination table, I get `b"Incorrect syntax near '\\'`

I assume this occurs, because the `varbinary(512)` is not escaped correctly. (i currently just have a `str()` wrapped around it.

How can I escape a `varbinary(512)` from a MSSQL database, saved in a string tuple, to use it in a `SELECT/INSERT WHERE` query?